# Public method in public inheritance becomes private in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance, public-method

I have a base class with a public method, but when I try to call it from a derived class which inherits publicly from the base class it becomes private. How is it possible? Shouldn't public inheritance means that public methods are kept public?

These is the base class and the method I am referring to is the method `r()` specifically

```
#define POTENTIALS_HPP

#include <cmath>
#include "Matrix.hpp"
#include "Physics_constants.hpp"
#include "PotentialData.hpp"

class Potential {
public:
    Potential() {}
    Potential(int l, int s, int j, double Mmu) : m_l(l), m_s(s), m_j(j),
        m_Mmu(Mmu){}
    virtual void setL(int) = 0;
    virtual void setS(int) = 0;
    virtual void setJ(int) = 0;
    virtual void setR(double) = 0;
    ushort l() const {return m_l;}
    ushort s() const {return m_s;}
    ushort j() const {return m_j;}
    double r() const {return m_r;}
    double Mr() const {return m_Mmu;}
    ~Potential() {}

    virtual Matrix<double> operator () () const = 0;
    virtual Matrix<double> operator () (double) = 0;
    Matrix<double> Veff() const {
        if (m_l==0 || m_r == 0)
            return (*this)();
        Matrix<double> p = (*this)();
        Matrix<double> L(p.cols());
        for (uint i=0; i<L.cols(); i++)
            L[i][i] = (m_l+2*i)*(m_l+2*i+1);
        L = L*(pow(Physics::Nuclear::hc,2)/(2*m_Mmu*m_r*m_r));
        std::cout << m_Mmu << "  " << m_r << std::endl;
        std::cout << p-L << std::endl;
        abort();
        return p-L;
    }
    Matrix<double> Veff(double r) {
        setR(r);
        return Veff();
    }

protected:
    ushort m_l;
    ushort m_s;
    ushort m_j;
    double m_r;
    double m_Mmu;
};

#endif // POTENTIALS_HPP
```

and this is the derived class

```
#ifndef ALPHAD_POTENTIAL_HAMMACHE_HPP
#define ALPHAD_POTENTIAL_HAMMACHE_HPP

#include "Physics_constants.hpp"
#include "Potentials.hpp"
#include <cmath>

class HammachePotential : public Potential {
public:
    HammachePotential() { m_s = 1; m_Mmu = PotentialData::Hammache::Mr;}
    HammachePotential(int l, int j) : Potential(l,1,j,PotentialData::Hammache::Mr) {
        if (l==0)
            V0 = 60.712;
        else
            V0 = 56.7;
        setLS2(l,s,j);
    }

    void setS(int) override {m_s=1;}

    void setL(int l) override {
        this->l = l;

        if (l==0)
            V0 = 60.712;
        else
            V0 = 56.7;
        setLS2(l,s,j);
    }
    void setJ(int j) override {
        this->j = j;
        setLS2(l,s,j);
    }
    void setR(double r) override {
        if (r==0)
            return;
        this->r = r;

        EXPR = expr(r);
        EXPRM1 = exprm1(EXPR);
    }

    std::tuple<int,int,int,double> getInfo() const {
        return {l,s,j,r};
    }

    double getVcDepth() const {
        return V0;
    }


    Matrix<double> operator () () const {
        if (r==0)
            return Matrix<double>(1);
        double Vc = -V0*EXPRM1;
        double Ve = Vem(r);
        double Vso= VSO*EXPR*std::pow(EXPRM1,2)/r;
        Matrix<double> ret(1);
        ret[0][0] = Vc+Ve+Vso;
        return ret;
    }

    Matrix<double> operator () (double r) {
        if (r==0)
            return Matrix<double>(1);
        setR(r);
        double Vc = -V0*EXPRM1;
        double Ve = Vem(r);
        double Vso= VSO*EXPR*std::pow(EXPRM1,2)/r;
        Matrix<double> ret(1);
        ret[0][0] = Vc+Ve+Vso;
        return ret;
    }



private:
    const double a =    0.65; //fm
    const double r0 =   1.25; //fm
    const double R =    r0*std::pow(6.,1./3); //fm
    const double l2 =   4.; //fm^2 -> lambda^2
    int l = 0;
    const int s = 1;
    int j = 1;
    int LS2;
    double V0;
    const double V1 = 2.4; //MeV
    const double coul = 2*Physics::alpha*Physics::Nuclear::hc;
    const double VSOfac0 = -V1*l2/a;
    double VSO;
    double r;
    double EXPR;
    double EXPRM1;

private:
    inline void setLS2(int l, int s, int j) {
        LS2 = j*(j+1) - l*(l+1) - s*(s+1);
        VSO = VSOfac0*LS2;
    }
    inline double Vem(double r) const {
        if (r<=R)
            return coul*(3-std::pow(r/R,2))/(2*R);
        else
            return coul/r;
    }
    inline double expr(double r) const {
        return std::exp( (r-R)/a );
    }
    inline double exprm1 (double expr) const {
        return 1.0/(1.0 + expr);
    }
};
#endif // ALPHAD_POTENTIAL_HAMMACHE_HPP
```

Edit:
The compiler output is

````
...main.cpp:184: error: ‘double HammachePotential::r’ is private within this context
...main.cpp:184:30: error: ‘double HammachePotential::r’ is private within this context
  184 |             std::cout << pot.r() << std::endl;
      |                              ^```

The error is also for the methods `l()`, `s()`, `j()`, but not `Mr()`.

I will soon try to reproduce a minimal example of it and see how it goes. I am sorry, but I am new asking questions here.
````

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. With emphasis on the *minimal* part. And include a copy-paste (as text) of the full and complete build-log from the shown example.

Comment: *I try to call it from a derived class which inherits publicly from the base class it becomes private.* It's always better to post the exact and complete compiler error message instead of describing it.

Comment: *the method I am referring to is the method `r()` specifically.* So the most other code is irrelevant? Please take a look at how to make a [mcve].

Comment: BTW `r()` is never called in the shown large code.

Comment: @Alan, please don't completely rewrite other users' questions.

Comment: @ChrisGPTwasonstrike I didn't, I just removed the extraneous information. Aren't we supposed to help new users rather than just closing and deleting their questions?

Comment: Such a lengthy wall of text but it isn't even showing the sourcecode where the compiler actually is complaining.
There are tons of completely unrelated functions that all just clutter the question, and it shows a general lack of naming or styleguides. There are members with single-letter names,  even some all-caps with methods with the same name just lowercase. You will get many many more errors in your code when writing like that.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf I did fix all that but Chris didn't like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a private member variable `r` in `HammachePotential` which shadows the method in `Potential`. Make sure to check the full error message from your compiler, GCC at least gives enough hints to work this out:
https://godbolt.org/z/bbv5v9feh

```
<source>:188:7: error: 'double HammachePotential::r' is private within this context
  188 |     a.r();
      |       ^
<source>:162:12: note: declared private here
  162 |     double r;
      |            ^
<source>:188:8: error: expression cannot be used as a function
  188 |     a.r();
      |     ~~~^~
```